# How to load specific fields only when load Elastic Search index to use elasticsearch input plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-plugin, logstash-configuration

I try to move the data from the index of the Elastic Search to the other index by using the log stash.

and, I want that move to specific field(world) from logstash index into test index.

so, I create a logstash config file.

The config file like this.

```
input {
 elasticsearch {
  hosts => "hostname"
  index => "logstash-2017.03.17"
  query => `{"fileds" : ["world"]}`
}

filter {

}

output {
 elasticsearch {
  hosts => "hostname"
  index => "test-${+YYYY.MM.DD}"
  action => "index"
}
}
```

but, logstash is not run by error

```
A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
  Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::Elasticsearch hosts=>["tales-gameelk"], index=>"logstash-2017.03.23", query=>"\"fields\" : [\"world\"]", codec=><LogStash::Codecs::JSON charset=>"UTF-8">, scan=>true, size=>1000, scroll=>"1m", docinfo=>false, docinfo_target=>"@metadata", docinfo_fields=>["_index", "_type", "_id"], ssl=>false>
  Error: [400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to derive xcontent"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"init_scan","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"logstash-2017.03.23","node":"5tE8NEF5T5uQbdrjb4yFiQ","reason":{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to derive xcontent"}}]},"status":400} {:level=>:error}
```

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `elasticsearch` input is malformed. Try this instead:

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "hostname"
    index => "logstash-2017.03.17"
    query => '{"_source" : ["world"]}'
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is solved by your comment. Thank you very much.